# I get syntax error when using loadlibrary i Matlab R2020b

Tags: matlab, dllimport

I try to load a DLL library supplied together with an instrument,

and get syntax error from the compiler.

Error Message:

```
Error using loadlibrary
__________________________________________________________________
Building CMMISDK_thunk_pcwin64 failed.  Compiler output is:
cl -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\extern\include" /Zp8  /W3  /nologo  -I"R:\ Matlab" -I"R:\ Matlab" "CMMISDK_thunk_pcwin64.c" -LD -Fe"CMMISDK_thunk_pcwin64.dll"
CMMISDK_thunk_pcwin64.c
R:\ Matlab\SDK_Error.h(10): error C2059: syntax error: ':'
______________________________________________________________________
```

And lines  6-14 in the "SDK_Error.h" file

```
_______________________________________________________________________________________
typedef signed int          int32_km;           //!< 32bit(signed)



enum error_km : int32_km  // line 10
{
    KmSuccess = 0,              `your text` //The processing was completed normally.
    KmWarning = 1,  
};
__________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Seems that the enum declaration is not accepted.

Experimented a bit with removing the part after the colon,
but other errors occured.

Comment: The error message and code you've provided indicate that there is an issue with the syntax of the `enum` declaration in the "SDK_Error.h" file. The error message specifically points to line 10 where the enum is defined

Comment: You might need to upgrade your C compiler, or add a flag to specify the newer C standard. This is very new syntax for C, it was added in the C23 specification.